# Django DeleteView only works on second attempt

Tags: python, django

Bit of a strange one and wondering if anyone else here has come across this.

I have a standard DeleteView with the GET showing a confirmation page containing a form that posts to the delete view.

Whenever I click confirm nothing happens - the post to the view occurs and it redirects as intended, however the object is not deleted.

If I then perform the action a second time the object is deleted.

```
class MetricDeleteView(DeleteView):
    template_name = "dashboard/administration/metric/delete.html"
    button_title = "Update metric"
    form_class = MetricUpdateForm
    model = dashboard_metric

    @cached_property
    def dashboard_score(self):
        return self.get_object().score

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("administration:dashboard:update_score", kwargs={
            'dashboard': self.dashboard_score.dashboard.id,
            'pk': self.dashboard_score.id
        })
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is occurring across all some models on my site.

Comment: maybe just have the last two lines in the post view and then specify the success_url below model = dashboard_metric

Comment: @tushortz I've removed the post method as it's not actually used, I was just seeing if the same would occur if I tried to manually delete ( which it did ). I've left dashboard_score in to save someone the time of commenting it might not be working be because get_success_url is referencing a property not defined in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, interesting. As the view is generic, have you looked at the model to check it doesn't override the delete functionality? Perhaps it doesn't delete on the first pass and sets a variable to 'deleted' instead, especially if you're working with syncing across platforms. WatermelonDB, for instance. Nathan. :D

Comment: Yeah looks like I was subclassing a model that overrides the default save method. Thanks Hannah.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).